# Reference Error : .match is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, open-source, codeigniter-3

Since the update to jQuery 3, dropdown box no longer functions as it should.
using jQuery migrate to help things along.

I had at first thought it was a loading issue and did the onload check trick to check that jquery is actually being loaded.

I had also tried rewriting the functions following best practices from the main jquery website but still no joy.

Code:

JS

```
var selectedModule = '';

function getTemplate(el){
    selectedModule = $(el).attr('value');

    if (selectedModule.match('!')){
        selectedModule = '';
        $(el).attr('value', '');
        alert('Please select a template within the module.');
    }

    if (selectedModule != ''){
        $('.showModuleName').hide();
        $('#templateName').val(selectedModule);

        if (selectedModule == 'custom'){
            $('.showModulePath').show();
        }
        else {
            $('.showModulePath').hide();
            $('#modulePath').val(selectedModule);
        }
    }
    else if (selectedModule == ''){
        $('.showModuleName').show();
        $('.showModulePath').hide();
    }
}

function loadTemplate(data){
    $('textarea#body').val(data);
}


function revertTemplate(){
    if (confirm('By doing this you will lose any unsaved changes. Are you sure?')){

        getTemplate($('select#moduleSelect'));

        if (selectedModule == ''){
            $('textarea#body').val("{include:header}\n\n{block1}\n\n{include:footer}");
        } else {
            $.get($('select#moduleSelect').attr('rel')+'/'+selectedModule, loadTemplate);
        }

        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

$(function(){
    $('select#moduleSelect').change(function(){
        revertTemplate();
    });

    $('input#default').click(function(){
        revertTemplate();
    });

    getTemplate($('select#moduleSelect'));

});
```

HTML / PHP

```
<div class="showModuleName">
  <label for="templateName">Name:</label>
  <?php echo form_input('templateName',set_value('templateName', $data['templateName']), 'id="templateName" class="formelement"'); ?>
  <br class="clear" /><br/>
</div>

<label for="moduleSelect">Module:</label>
<?php
  $values = array();
  $values[''] = 'Not a module template';
  $values['divider'] = '---------------------------';
  if (in_array('blog', $this->permission->permissions)) $values['!blog'] = 'Blog';
  if (in_array('blog', $this->permission->permissions)) $values['blog'] = '-- View Posts';
  if (in_array('blog', $this->permission->permissions)) $values['blog_single'] = '-- Single Post';
  if (in_array('blog', $this->permission->permissions)) $values['blog_search'] = '-- Blog Search Results';

  $values['custom'] = 'Custom Module';

  echo @form_dropdown('moduleSelect',$values, (($data['templateName'] == 'custom') ? 'custom' : $data['modulePath']), 'id="moduleSelect" class="formelement" rel="'.site_url('/admin/pages/module').'"');
?>
<span class="tip">To make a module template (e.g. for the Blog) select the module here.</span>
<br class="clear" /><br/>

<div class="showModulePath">
  <label for="modulePath">Module Reference:</label>
  <?php echo @form_input('modulePath',set_value('modulePath', $data['modulePath']), 'id="modulePath" class="formelement"'); ?>
  <br class="clear" /><br/>
</div>
```

---

Links:

JS Code

```
(https://pastebin.com/QuWyjjVe)
```

[Github Source](https://github.com/Forgeigniter/ForgeIgniter-CI-3.x/blob/v2.x/static/js/templates.js)

Comment: Links to code aren't very helpful. They can become broken and then people searching for a similar question in the future might not be able to access them. Please include all **relevant** code in your question. :-)

Comment: try `el.attr('value');` instead of `$(el).attr('value');`

Comment: Good point. Will update...

Comment: @Taki still no good.